# Why does DISABLE PRIMARY KEY CASCADE doesn't set Unique Index unusable?

Tags: oracle, indexing, primary-key, cascade

can anyone explain to me why the execution of "DISABLE PRIMARY KEY CASCADE" on a PK doesn't set the corresponding unique (!) index to unusable?

As far as I know the CASCADE option should do exactly that... However, I observed differently on several occasions.

Hope some of you can help.

best regards,
daZza

Comment: Do you have more specific circumstances? The index should actually be dropped, not invalidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cascade option disables constraints that are dependent on this one, such as foreign keys dependent on a primary or unique constraint.

A unique index is not a constraint, although it acts as one.

In general I would advise that you create non-unique indexes to support a primary or unique key, not a unique index, for precisely this reason, and to allow constraints to be deferrable, or entirely dropped and recreated without having to recreate the index.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11547: "When the database is using a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY index to enforce a constraint, and constraints associated with that index are dropped or disabled, the index is dropped, unless you specify otherwise"

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. I don't believe that there is such a thing as a "PRIMARY KEY index". I'd better run a test or two ...

Comment: Thanks. After more manual testing it seems to be the case that only FKs and such are also disabled.

I just programmed another loop to set all the UNIQUE-Indexes unusable.

Comment: You might like to rebuild them as nonunique for future purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the indexes in question are UNIQUE on purpose. I am disabling them just for performance reasons while executing big updates...